# run script when other script is done changing the dom

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" id="foo" async=false defer=false src="../misc/bna.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async=false defer=false>

function remove_double_banners() {
   // ...
}
remove_double_banners();
```

The bna scripts is changing things in the DOM.
I want the other script with the `remove_double_banners` to execute after the bna script is done.

I tried:

- have the script block at the end of body
- have the script block after the body
- 

```js
var script = document.querySelector('#foo');
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
        remove_double_banners();    
});
```

- 

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", remove_double_banners);
```

The only thing that works is:

```js
setTimeout(function(){ remove_double_banners(); }, 100);
```

But that is really bad practice.

How can I run a script after "bna.js" is done changing the DOM, without changing the "bna.js" script?

Comment: How complx is the bna.js? Can you change the code of it? The best way is to wirte code in it..

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: You can use async chaining with .then() and .finally(). Set it up kind of like a fetch operation, you will find the solution if you Google fetch tutorial, for example.

Comment: @ArtemMedianyk Not complex, but I want to avoid changing as a practice.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I will look into it, it looks promising.

Comment: @anatolhiman I still need to change `bna.js` then.

Comment: @ArtemMedianyk MutationObserver did the trick! Not sure what the overhead is, since I'm not interested in the mutations, but at least I know it's done then.